# How to check strings from multiple lines in one input field?

Tags: unity, c#, input

I need help with input fields. I already set the line type to 'Multi_Line NewLine' in inspector, but I have problem with submitting the string. Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    public string code;
    public string code1;
    [SerializeField]
    public InputField input;

    public void Check(string guess)
    {
        if (string.Equals (guess,code)) {
            Debug.Log ("correct");
        } else
            Debug.Log ("wrong");
    }
    public void GetInput(string guess)
    {
        Check (guess);
        input.text = "";

    }
}
```

I want to have both 'code' and 'code1' strings to be inserted in different lines inside the same input field but I don't know how to check both 'code' and 'code1' string value inside the Check(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check `System.Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: How to do that though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `guess` variable will have a text from InputField, if so you could use this line to split the string from checking to NewLine

```
string[] guessWords = guess.Split('\n');
```

and then retrieving the specific word from the `guessWords` array like

```
if (string.Equals(guessWords[0], code))
{
    Debug.Log("code 1 correct");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("code 1 wrong");
}
if (string.Equals(guessWords[1], code1))
{
    Debug.Log("code 2 correct");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("code 2 wrong");
}
```

note you may still need to handle `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you only input one line to InputField